# Will a newer model Router/AP provide better WiFi coverage than my existing Netgear WAC104 (AC1200) dual-band AP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

1. Summarize the problem

I'm trying to determine if a newer router/AP will help improve wifi in our house. I guess my real question is whether the newer "whole house" routers do actually provide wider coverage through walls or whether I should live with my existing cheaper APs, including this Netgear WAC104 that isn't working very well.

Regarding a new Router/AP

I don't really need the routing functions because I am seriously considering an Edgerouter to handle routing /lan segmenting. Also the position of where the Fibre comes in is not ideal for Wifi coverage.

I just want to know, from any of your experiences out there, about the Wifi in these new routers that claim giant square footage specs and "beamforming" and all this other stuff.  Is it worth shelling out $300 for one of these, if I'm just going to use it as an AP?  Are these new routers actually better at Wifi coverage or is it all marketing?  Am I better off getting Ubiquiti APs or something else?

2. Provide details and any research

Wifi coverage is terrible in our 3-story (+basement) Toronto townhouse (think long, very skinny and tall).  We have the admittedly poor Bell HH3000 on the main floor providing 2.4GHz and 5GHz for the main and basement, but the signal doesn't reach well on the same floor even, and is quite unreliable in the basement (drops connections, refuses to connect, etc.)

3. When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried

A few years ago I bought a Netgear WAC104 AP to use for the second/3rd floors, but its coverage is poor even when centrally located. It's hard-wired via a stable powerline connection that delivers consistently 250Mbps. The Wifi connections to the WAC104 are unstable in any room that's not immediately adjacent to the AP, weirdly the 5GHz band is considerably better than 2.4GHz.  This WAC104 is also freakishly unstable in its own right.  I need to reboot it regularly and it has no way to do so via the gui, so I have to manually unplug it.  *sigh*

For awhile I repurposed a few older DD-WRT 2.4GHz routers and put them in more places, but the problems with different SSID's, with phones/devices connected to "wrong" one are just giving me headaches. I can't remember to switch SSID's every time I go to a different room, and my wife and daughter can't remember which is which.

I tried turning off the 5GHz signal on the HH3000 to see if there was too much congestion on the channels, but that didn't seem to help much.  There are about 6~8 neighborhood APs that I can see with a Wifi analyzer but that's not too crazy, I think.

Any advice?  I'd like to avoid mesh if possible because we are soon going to be renting out parts of the house and I'd like to be able to set up either Guest wifi access or have separate lan segments from the edgegrouter. I dunno, maybe mesh can do all this better than I imagine?  I also don't want to go through the "buy it out and try it out and return it if it doesn't do what you want" rigamarole.

Comment: WiFi is still and will always be limited by the materials of walls and floors.  Your range might improve a little but if your basement has a concrete celling your still probably not going to get any signal in it.  5 GHz is even more sensitive to building materials.  What you probably should do is run copper to each floor and use a unified system.  Yes; Something like Ubiquiti does make that easy.  The faster the radio frequency, the more sensitive it will be to range and building materials, but provide higher bandwidths

Comment: Thanks.  I've been looking at the Ubiquiti APs in the hours since I posted this. The main and basement have cat5e wiring to several wall jacks so this seems the best route.  If I get all Unifi APs then it seems I can mesh the system or split them according to which apartments we rent out. I'm leaning very much in this direction now for flexibility and reliability.

Comment: Following up to my own question. I did buy a used Edgerouter ER-X and 2 Ubiquiti UAP-AC-LITE access points (APs).  So far I have one AP mounted horizontally in the basement and one AP mounted vertically on the second floor. The wifi coverage and stability is signicantly improved. Generally I am able to receive 100Mbps+ throughout the house and I don't need to reset the APs twice a day like I did with my previous Netgear. In all I'm glad that I went with a system that separates router from Wifi.  Maybe consumer mesh would have worked just as well but I'm pleased with the power and flexibility.

Comment: Why isn’t that an answer?